# Web scraping scr from <img> tag ,getting a weird output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'am trying to webscrap "https://www.carwale.com/maruti-suzuki-cars/" using python-->requests and beautifulsoup. Here it is returning the source of all the image tag, but the problem here is, only first two links are only proper, the remaining are some stranger link in .gif format.

**[Git Repo](https://github.com/Nishan666/car-data-scraper)**

### code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

# getting html data fromm url
page = requests.get("https://www.carwale.com/maruti-suzuki-cars/", headers=headers)

# here the BeautifulSoup module is used to access the conent inside the scraped data
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')   

for i in soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': "o-fzptUA"}) : 
    print(i.find('img')['src'])
    # or
    # print(i.find('img').get("src"))
```

### output

[image]

## Aim of my Project

The aim of my project is to get all the image links from src tag.